# Task and return type

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a question regarding Tasks. I understand that we should choose `Task` if we need the method to be awaited, `void` if we don't need it, and `Task<T>` if we are returning something. Right? Now I am using `Task<T>` and taking parameter `List<Article>` that is returned from an API and returning `return Task.CompletedTask;` However I am not completely sure this is correct.

```cs
async Task<Task> FillAnonymousArticles(List<Article> articles)
{
    foreach (var article in articles)
    {
        var filename = string.Format(SharedConstants.ArticleImageUrl, SharedConstants.ApiBaseUri, article.Id);
        var newCell = new ArticleDetailData()
        {
            Author = article.Author,
            BackgroundImage = filename,
            Id = article.Id,
            Subtitle = article.Description,
            Title = article.Name,
        };
        var sec = article.Category;
        if (sec == null)
        {
            newCell.Section = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            newCell.Section = article.Category;
        }
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Should `allUserArticles` be `articles` (from the method parameters)?  I don't see anything in here that needs async/task, unless this is a toy example

Comment: Returning `Task.CompletedTask;` doesn't cause the method to run asynchronously. The current method will just run synchronously.

Comment: Your question is unclear, and cannot be answered in any good, useful way. It's certainly unusual to have any method return `Task<Task>`. That extra level of indirection is almost never appropriate or needed. And without an `await`, there's no reason at all for the method to be `async`. But without more context, it's impossible to say whether any part of the code you posted is correct.

Comment: `Task<Task>` doesn't make sense either, it could have been `async Task FillAnonymousArticles()` with the exact same result. No, you cannot make an otherwise synchronous method asynchronous by making it return `Task`.

Comment: Shouldn't something happen with `newCell`? Don't you need to add them to a new list and return this list? Otherwise, this method would do nothing, except consuming CPU cycles with no visible result.

Comment: And looks like you need to do some research about async concepts; Such questions without doing research causes downvotes and finally getting question banned like me:)

Comment: @GSerg: _"it could have been `async Task FillAnonymousArticles()` with the exact same result"_ -- that's not actually true. If the caller is expecting an asynchronous method with a result type of `Task`, then `Task<Task>` _is_ needed. In any case, it's certainly not true that the return type can be arbitrarily changed as you suggest and yet still have literally **the exact same result**. You've changed the result type, so naturally it can't be **the exact** same result. I agree that it's unlikely `Task<Task>` is correct here, but there's not enough context to know for sure.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree I could have put that better. My point was that currently the method is an async that does not return a meaningful result, but can be awaited. Being awaitable is its only useful property. Exactly the same can be achieved with just `Task`.

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi thank you, i see that you are right. However I dont mind to get that points down .. I am learning by myself and sometimes using google and youtube still requires some more information and this website is the only page where i can ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first part of the question:
You return Task or Task if your method does a I/O call, or a long running CPU intensive calculation and you don't want the caller thread to be blocked while this operation is being performed.

You return void or a direct value in your method doesn't fit the above criteria.

There is a third case where you declare an async void method in case your method does I/O call or long running CPU calculation, but your need to call it by something that expects a void Return type, such as in a button click handler in Winforms or WPF application.

Another case is a method that performs the task asynchronously but the caller expects a Task or Task results. In this case you return Task.CompletedTask or Task.FromResult(value)

The method in your code sample is not performing a long CPU intensive operation, or an I/O call. There is no need to define it as async. You can just have a void return type, or if your caller expects a Task return type, then make return type Task and return Task.CompletedTask without making the method async.